# What bicycle is this? The handlebars and stand are at an unusual angle

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I have this bike from the 80s/90s (4719, red). I wanted to buy another one, but I can’t find this specific version on BrickLink:

[image: side view of the bicycle]

[image: top view of the bicycle]

The handle bar and stand are at an angle, so the bike can be leaned to a wall conveniently. But I can only find bikes with straight handle bars.

There are three *LEGO* marks on the frame (inside the headlight and on both sides of the pedal axis), as well as the lettering `4 7 1 9` on the left side of the frame, and `1` on the right.

Does anyone know from which set this is … or the specific name of this part?

**Edit:** Here’s a close-up of the handle bar and I can see that it definitely was twisted:

[image: close-up of the handle bar]

It was probably forgotten under a heavy box over the summer, or something like that!

Comment: It makes sense that it probably got warped over time, because look at the incongruity between the handlebars and the front wheel. If it had been manufactured that way, you'd expect that Lego would have molded the wheel to be in line with the handlebars.

Comment: @nick012000 Likewise, if someone had intentionally cut and glued, or heated and bent the handlebars, you'd think they'd have done the same with the front wheel.  All signs point to it being flattened under something heavy.

Comment: RE: "The handle bar and stand are at an angle, so the bike can be leaned to a wall conveniently." - if this was intentionally for "leaning against a wall", there wouldn't be a kickstand.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The number indicates [part 4719 - bicycle frame](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4719&name=Bicycle%20Frame&category=%5BRiding%20Cycle%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).

[image: Image from bricklink, as described below]

As you can see, it has a straight handlebars and kickstand. Your particular piece must have been modified to fit some specific purpose. Lego does not reuse the same mold numbers much, and never on the purpose, so I highly doubt if it was molded that way.

Comment: The kickstand has a very distinct form (it’s not twisted, rather the bottom vertices are rotated and the top vertices are not, connected via straight lines). I’ll take photos tomorrow. I can’t imagine how this could have been produced without being molded this way, but then again I’m no expert.

Comment: @Krishty I've seen parts cut and glued with enough precision. Usually in wargaming miniatures, but I did.

Comment: I also wonder if heat combined with turning pressure over a long period of time would allow this modification without any seam at all.

Comment: Heat over a long period of time is a good theory. I played with this bike in 1995, so whatever happened to it is long forgotten. I’ll look at the fine edges with magnifying glasses, maybe I can take a few photos to solve the matter once and for all.

Comment: @Mołot I’m sure you’re right; see updated photo of handle bar. I accepted your answer; thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a similar one (4719c02) but with a new-style frame with open stud (still 4719) and new wheels (92851pb01). Although this one does not have the twisted kickstand.

[image: Lego bicycle 4719c02 with twisted handlebars]
[image: Lego bicycle 4719c02 with twisted handlebars]
[image: Lego bicycle 4719c02 with twisted handlebars, Top view]

Comment: Where/how did you find it?

Comment: I wish I had a concrete answer, but it came from a used-bulk lot from either eBay or Catawiki. There's no way to trace it back.